# Is it possible to send attachment using Send-PnPMail in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, office365

Is it possible to send attachment using Send-PnPMail in Powershell ?

Send-PnPMail -To $requestor -Subject "Teams App Provisioning Delta Load - $(Get-Date)" -Body "Requested Teams App for $($user) Provisioned Successfully"

Comment: Based on the documentation it is not available. Did you try `Send-MailMessage`? Or better, why don't you want to use `Send-MailMessage`?

Comment: Send-MailMessage - As per the documentation, we must specify a Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) server. 

Is it possible to send attachment via email using Powershell without SMTP.

I would need to send the SharePoint list data as a csv attachment via email to users.